# Fetch and display tweets of particular user using html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, twitter

I need to fetch and display the tweets of a particular user and display them using simple HTML. How can I do that?
I am new to this kind of topic. At least some start would be greatful.

Comment: Using twitter api, for example.

Comment: It wasn't me, but, I guess, somebody downvoted you, because you didn't show any effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official guide to the Twitter API is Twitter's [Developer Center](https://dev.twitter.com/). They have a really nice list of [FAQs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api-faq) that can get you started.

If all you're interested in is getting a user's tweets, see [Using the Twitter Search API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search) and the [GET search](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search) docs page.

For some sample code to get you started, see Knockout.js's [Twitter client example](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/twitter.html).